# Override function if defined in the object else default functionality

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have `calendar` widget which is written in `TypeScript`. I can bind listener to separate function, but i want this separate function to have default functionality until someone overrides the function in the `config` object passed to the constructor. In the constructor I'm passing something similar

```
{
  container: 'xxx',
  cellClick: function(sender, event, data) {
    // custom functionality
  }
}
```

How can i define an function `cellClick` in my base class and when i render my `td` cells to bind event listener to this function and pass some data for the cell which will have some default functionality for the cell, but if someone is defined the function in the object to override it with the data for the cell clicked.

I do it similar to that but this binds the listener directly to the `config` function. I bet its really easy to do that in my `setter` but i cant figure it how.

```
td.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.config.cellClick(td, event, data);
})
```

**EDIT:**
This is my `abstract` class which extends `Table` class which simply creates objects for `thead, tbody and tfoot`

```
defaultConfig = {
                container: '',
                dataSource: [],
                currentDate: new Date(),
                currentView: 'month',
                views: [
                    { type: 'Day' },
                    { type: 'Week' },
                    { type: 'Month' }
                ],
                startDayHour: 8,
                endDayHour: 20,
                cellDuration: 60,
                todayHighlight: true,
                cellClick: this.cellClick,
                eventClick: this.eventClick,
                showAllDayPanel: false,
                disabledDays: [],
                resources: {
                    dataSource: [],
                    field: null
                },
                groupBy: null,
            }

            set config(cfg: my.core.calendar.iCalendarConfiguration) {
                if (cfg) {

                    for (var key in cfg) {
                        if (cfg[key] == null) {
                            cfg[key] = this.defaultConfig[key];
                        }
                    }

                    if (cfg.cellClick != null) {
                        cfg.cellClick.bind(this.cellClick);
                    }

                    this.configuration = cfg;
                    this.MonthLength = new Date(cfg.currentDate).getMonth();
                    this.weekDayStart = cfg.currentDate;
                    this.weekDayEnd = cfg.currentDate;
                }
            }

            get config(): iCalendarConfiguration {
                return this.configuration;
            }

            .............

            constructor(config: iCalendarConfiguration) {
                super();

                this.element.className = "table table-bordered table-responsive col-sm-12"; // could be readed from config but tbd
                this.config = config;
                this.appointmentsArray = config.dataSource;
                this.tools = new my.calendar.CalendarTools();

                /**
                 *  Append the element to the container
                 *  which is defined in the config.
                 */
                document.getElementById(config.container).appendChild(this.tools.createDiv('', 'row', this.parentID)).appendChild(this.element);
            }

            abstract createCalendar();

            abstract bindAppointments(view: string);

            abstract Next(sender, e, data)

            abstract Previous(sender, e, data)

            abstract TabClick(sender: any, event: any, data: any)

            abstract initialize()

            abstract onResize()

            abstract cellClick(sender: any, event: any, data: any)

            abstract eventClick(sender: any, event: any, data: any)
```

And there is a class `calendar` which extends the abstract class and its the class which is instanced with the configuration object.

```
export class Calendar extends my.core.calendar.CalendarTable {
        weeklyView: my.calendar.WeeklyView;
        monthlyView: my.calendar.MontlyView;
        dayView: my.calendar.DayView;

        constructor(cfg: my.core.calendar.iCalendarConfiguration) {
            super(cfg);

            this.weeklyView = new my.calendar.WeeklyView(this);
            this.monthlyView = new my.calendar.MontlyView(this);
            this.dayView = new my.calendar.DayView(this);
        }


        onResize() {
            /**
             *  Repaint all appointments on window resize
             *  For many reasons
             */
            this.bindAppointments();
        }

        createCalendar() {

            /** Clear everything on change */
            if (this.tBody.rows.length > 0) {
                this.tBody.clear();
                this.tHead.clear();
            }

            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.createMontlyView();
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.createDayView();
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.createWeeklyView();
                    break;
            }

            this.bindAppointments();
        }

        bindAppointments() {
            /** Remove the events div for week/day view. Its here because reasons. */
            if (this.element.parentElement.querySelector("#events") !== null) {
                let child = document.getElementById('events');

                this.element.parentElement.removeChild(child);
            }

            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.bindMonthAppointments();
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.bindDayAppointments();
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.bindWeekAppointments();
                    break;
            }
        }

        Next(sender, e, data) {
            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.monthNavigationChange(true);
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.dayNavigationChange(true);
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.weekNavigationChange(true);
                    break;
            }
            this.createCalendar();
            this.updateLabels();
        }

        Previous(sender, e, data) {
            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.monthlyView.monthNavigationChange(false);
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.dayView.dayNavigationChange(false);
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.weeklyView.weekNavigationChange(false);
                    break;
            }
            this.createCalendar();
            this.updateLabels();
        }

        TabClick(sender: any, event: any, data: any) {

            switch (sender.id.toLowerCase()) {
                case "day":
                    this.tools.setActiveTab(this, 'day', event);
                    // update currentdate
                    break;
                case "month":
                    this.tools.setActiveTab(this, 'month', event);
                    // update currentdate
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.tools.setActiveTab(this, 'week', event);
                    // update currentdate
                    break;
            }
            this.createCalendar();
            this.updateLabels();
        }


        updateLabels() {
            let date = new Date(this.config.currentDate);
            switch (this.config.currentView) {
                case "month":
                    this.currentDateMonth.value = String(this.calendar_months_label[date.getMonth()]) + ' ' + String(date.getFullYear());
                    break;
                case "day":
                    this.currentDateMonth.value = String(this.config.currentDate.getDate()) + ' ' + String(this.calendar_months_label[this.config.currentDate.getMonth()]) + ' ' + String(this.config.currentDate.getFullYear());
                    break;
                case "week":
                    this.currentDateMonth.value = String(this.tools.getPreviousWeekStr(this.weekStart, this.weekEnd, this.calendar_months_label[this.config.currentDate.getMonth()], this.config.currentDate.getFullYear()));
                    break;
            }
        }

        initialize() {
            this.tools.createNavigation(this, this.config);
            this.createCalendar();
            this.bindAppointments();
        }

        cellClick(sender, event, data) {
            console.log('fired up from mycalendar');
        }

        eventClick(sender, event, data) {

        }

    }; // end class basic
```

There is 3 more classes for the `view` render,logic etc which get the table object and do some stuff.

And here is how i initialize it.

```
var calendar = new my.calendar.Calendar({
        container: 'calendarTestContainer',
        dataSource: data,
        views: [
            { type: 'Week' },
            { type: 'Day' },
            { type: 'Month' }
        ],
        currentDate: new Date('2017-03-15'),
        currentView: 'week',
        startDayHour: 8,
        disabledDays: [6],
        cellDuration: 30,
        resources: {
            dataSource: staffs,
            field: 'UID'
        },
        endDayHour: 24,
        cellClick: function (sender, e, data) {
            // this has to be overrided
        },
        showAllDayPanel: true
    }).initialize();
```

**Since I'm not really in OOP** I'm open for re-factor suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may provide a default object with your default functions:

```
defaults = {
    option1: 'value1',
    cellClick: function() {/*do your default stuff here*/}
}
```

When you have your config object, you can merge them using `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(defaults, config || {});
```

Your `defaults` object now contains all the default values unless there were values in your `config` object. Now you can use

```
td.addEventListener('click', defaults.cellClick)
```

This adds your default function or the overwriting function as handler.

Comment: Seems nice, but i want cell click to be an class method and not an function in object. If i call the class method in the default cellClick will it work?

Comment: Since ``defaults`` should be a property of your class, you can use ``defaults = {cellClick: theNameOfYourMethod}``. If this is still not suitable, you should share the relevant part of your class (as InferOn already commented).

Comment: I did it. Edited with the class

Comment: Maybe i'm missing some coffee, but your overwriting of your config values is odd. You should be looping through the keys of your ``defaultConfig``, overwrite the values there and use the defaultConfig object as your configuration (or you use the snippet above). You should then be able to use ``cfg.cellClick`` as your handler function. Also ``cfg.cellClick.bind(this.cellClick);`` is strange since you do not need the context of ``this.cellClick``.

Comment: Ahh, that seems more legit :), I'll try it now. Thanks for the help.